# How to do a mutual deletion of a one-to-one in Symfony?

Tags: inheritance, symfony1, doctrine, one-to-one

I have tables with a one-to-one. In my config/doctrine/schema.yml, my both tables respectively have:

```
TableA:
  #...
  relations:
    TableB: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: table_a_id }
```

et

```
TableB:
  #...
  relations:
    TableA: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: table_a_id, foreign: id }
```

When I delete a TableA element, the corresponding element in TableB also deletes itself. But this does not work the other way.

How to do a mutual deletion of a one-to-one in Symfony ?

---

**@Pabloks** : I understand and it will go in the simplified case that I presented. But in reality, there are at least a third table. In fact, there is a notion of inheritance between the first table and the other two.

```
TableA:
  #...
  relations:
    TableB: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: table_a_id }
    TableC: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: table_a_id }

TableB:
  #...
  relations:
    TableA: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: table_a_id, foreign: id }

TableC:
  #...
  relations:
    TableA: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: table_a_id, foreign: id }
```

Comment: I don't use Doctrine 1 but I think it is because one the side of your one-to-one relationship is the 'owning side' (the one containing the foreign keys), Doctrine needs to know which entity works as the owning side in order to cascade operation. It's why it can't be "bidirectional" in this case.

Comment: You defined the same relation twice, please read [this page of the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/hu/defining-models:relationships:foreign-key-associations:one-to-one) especially the § under the schema.yml file. I think you might expect some strange things with your definition.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses which have the merit of being clear. So I guess the only solution is to code yourself this behavior in the model of the table ... Would you have an idea of the best approach? (I started in symfony)

Comment: I edit my answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In TableA you're doing fine, but in TableB you're defining the relation incorrectly.

The code must be like:

```
TableA:
  #...
  relations:
    TableB: { onDelete CASCADE, local: id, foreign: table_a_id }

et

TableB:
  #...
  relations:
    TableA: { onDelete CASCADE, local: id, foreign: table_b_id }
```

The parameter 'local' describes which field of the **current** model is related to the other model, 'foreign' describes which field of the **other** model is linked to the 'local' field.

Hope its clear.

Edit: thought that you're edit was wrong but check out later that was right. My mystake.